# Setting/app to route audio input to phone's mic while a wired headset is connected to it

Tags: applications, audio, microphone

I'm a new Android phone user. I'm looking for a setting or an application that can route audio input to phone's microphone while a wired headset is connected to it, but keep the audio output to the headset. I have been searching for this in Setting but I think it is not available there. I have been also searching for the app that can do this, the search results recommend me an app named SoundAbout, but it doesn't do what I want, it's just routing audio output to phone's speaker while a wired headset is connected to it.

So is there any?

Answer (score 1):

There is no system-wide setting for this, unfortunately. And apps that try to control audio routing are usually hacks that cause problems on their own.

But I have a hardware solution for you -- buy one of those splitter adaptors that convert 4-pin TRRS into 2 3-pin TRS, separating for headphones and microphone, and only plug the headphones jack into your phone. Look for something like this: [https://www.amazon.com/StarTech-MUYHSFMM-Headset-Splitter-Adapter/dp/B0058DOWH6](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0058DOWH6) (I'm not recommending this particular adapter, just showing how it should look like).

Answer (score -1):

Use an app named [Lesser AudioSwitch](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.nordskog.LesserAudioSwitch).

Comment: Hi, could you [edit] and expand the answer to explain why and how the app solves the issue? As of current writing, it's unclear why readers should use this app.